# SOLIDWORKS VBA Find uses of part or assembly

Tags: vba, solidworks, solidworksapi

I am trying to create a macro in SolidWorks VBA (SW 2020), that automatically finds uses of a specified part (or assembly possibly) within a set of search paths.

This should be used for example to rename a part and automatically update references, or to check uses before deleting a file.

This exact functionality is implemented as a function in the windows explorer context menu, but I cannot find the corresponding functions in the documentation.

What I have found is a very complicated alternative. If I first add the opened part to a new (temporary) assembly, rename the part and then save the assembly, I can use an object within an event to search for uses of the part. Basically what is done here: https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/sldworksapi/Rename_Component_and_Update_References_Example_VB.htm

My question is, if there is an easier way to do this, without first needing this dummy assembly and to rename the part.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In a part file there is no reference to the assemblies that use it.

You will have to go through each assemblies files in the directories, open them and look for the referenced parts with [ListExternalFileReferences](https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/sldworksapi/SOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks%7ESOLIDWORKS.Interop.sldworks.IModelDocExtension%7EListExternalFileReferences.html). You can also do it faster without opening the assemblies with Solidworks document manager [GetAllExternalReferences5](https://help.solidworks.com/2020/english/api/swdocmgrapi/SolidWorks.Interop.swdocumentmgr%7ESolidWorks.Interop.swdocumentmgr.ISwDMDocument21%7EGetAllExternalReferences5.html), see [example](https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-document-manager-api/document/get-external-references/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was wondering if this exact funcionality is already implemented and accessible in the API, but it seems it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically want to develop it on your own, I have used a tool called "Where-used" which is available here:

http://esoxrepublic.com/freeware/index.html

it works fine. Hope this helps.