Open referenced assembly in an open part in Solidworks using VBA
Curious, is it possible to open a referenced assembly of the part you have opened in Solidworks? The referenced assembly has an entirely other directory than the opened part.

Ist this the same question as https://stackoverflow.com/q/73231767/17172829 ?

You can use ListExternalFileReferences on the part to get the assembly, if there is a link to it in the part file. Otherwise you will have to search all assemblies for the part.
